# How to download a pdf in php?

Tags: php

This the code I used to generate simple pdf file in php using fpdf and I don't need to display in browser. I just need it to be downloaded when the page is load.

```
<?Php

  require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');

  $pdf = new FPDF();

  $pdf->AddPage();


  $date = date('Y-m-d');

  $width_cell = array(75, 75, 40);

  $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20);

  $pdf->Cell(50, 10, "Contact List( Downloaded on  " . $date . ")");

  $pdf->Ln();

  $pdf->Ln();

  $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 14);

  $pdf->SetFillColor(193, 229, 252); // Background color of header

  // Header starts ///

  $pdf->Cell($width_cell[0], 10, 'First Name', 1, 0, 'L', true); // First header column

  $pdf->Cell($width_cell[1], 10, 'Last Name', 1, 0, 'L', true); // Second header column

  $pdf->Cell($width_cell[2], 10, 'Contact Number', 1, 0, 'L', true); // Third header column

  $pdf->Ln();
  //// header ends ///////

  $pdf->SetFillColor(235, 236, 236); // Background color of header
  $fill = false; // to give alternate background fill color to rows

  /// end of records ///

  $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: I think you will need to be clearer as to what you mean. Do you want to pop up a "save" dialogue box in the user's browser after the web page has rendered? You cannot save anything to the user's drive without permission.

Comment: as we use some script to download the a particular page right? similarly the pdf should be downloaded to a temporary folder

Comment: I can't understand you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the readfile()-function.

```
int readfile ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = FALSE [, resource $context ]] )
```

This will read the file and write it into an output-buffer.

For any reference see

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Hope this helps

Comment: Dear sir/madam its manual downloading .i need to be get the generated file download automatically since when the page redirects to the pdf page

Answer (score 0):

I use m_pdf library in codeigniter to download generated pdf file this works for me. Maybe this help for you.

```
function generate_pdf($view_path, $view_data){
    $this->load->library('M_pdf');

    $directory_name = 'abc_pdf';
    $filename       = "abc.pdf";
    $pdfFilePath    = FCPATH."/uploads/".$directory_name.'/'.$filename;

    if (!is_dir(FCPATH.'/uploads/'.$directory_name)) {
        mkdir(FCPATH.'/uploads/' . $directory_name, 0777, TRUE);
    }

    if (file_exists($pdfFilePath)){
        unlink($pdfFilePath);
    }
    $html = $this->load->view('abc/'.$view_path, $view_data, true);
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output("./uploads/".$directory_name.'/'.$filename, "F");


    return $directory_name.'/'.$filename;
}
```

Comment: so this coverts the php page to pdf and gets downloaded ?

Comment: is it get download when the page is loaded ? or manually we need to click the button in the pdf template?

Comment: Its up to you how you use this function. for both cases this should work

Comment: still the pdf is viewing in the browser . i dont need to be displayed it should be directly downloaded to a folder .

Comment: can you share link ?

Comment: I can see pdf is downloaded on page refresh